# Opening Modal popup on Ajax form submission

Tags: ajax, jquery, forms

I´m migrating a form from an old website to a new one, but the jQuery modal that should open after the AJAX form submission doesn't work.

You can test it here https://tomlab.dreamhosters.com/sign-the-declaration/

The form seems to be working, but the popup is not showing up, but if I access https://tomlab.dreamhosters.com/sign-the-declaration/#modal straight, it opens up correctly.

Hope you can help me! I've been fighting with this for a few days.

Thanks!

Here is the function code:

```
function forms_sumate_func() {
    $lang = 'en';
    if ( get_locale() == 'es_ES' ) {
        $lang = 'es';
    }

    //$file = plugins_url() . '/forms-sumate/formulario-sumate-' . $lang . '.html';

    $file = ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/forms-sumate/formulario-sumate-' . $lang . '.html';

    return @file_get_contents($file);
}

add_shortcode( 'forms_sumate', 'forms_sumate_func' );

// incluimos js de formularios

function ajax_form_sumate_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'form_sumate_js', plugins_url() . '/forms-sumate/js/forms-sumate.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'form_sumate_css', plugins_url() . '/forms-sumate/css/forms-sumate.css' );
    wp_localize_script( 'form_sumate_js', 'forms_sumate_url', array( 'url_countries_json' => plugins_url() . '/forms-sumate/js/countries.json', 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'remodal_js', plugins_url() . '/remodal/js/remodal.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'remodal_js', plugins_url() . '/remodal/js/custom.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'remodal_css', plugins_url() . '/remodal/css/remodal.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'remodal_theme_css', plugins_url() . '/remodal/css/remodal-default-theme.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_form_sumate_enqueue_scripts' );

// Llamadas ajax

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_form_sumate', 'send_form_sumate' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_send_form_sumate', 'send_form_sumate' );
```

form-sumate.js

```
     // hola a todos
     
    
    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '#btn-enviar-personas', function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        
        sumateFormApp.init('#formPersonas');
    }); 
    

    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '#btn-enviar-entidades', function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        
        sumateFormApp.init('#formEntidades');
    });

    var sumateFormApp = {
        //Validate Contact Us Data
        validate: function (nameForm) {
            
            var $sumateFormName = jQuery(nameForm + " input[name='your-name']");
            var $sumateFormSurname = jQuery(nameForm + " input[name='your-surname']");
            var $sumateFormEmail = jQuery(nameForm + " input[name='your-email']");
            var $sumateFormCountry = jQuery(nameForm + " select[name='your-country'] option:selected");
            var $sumateFormPhone = jQuery(nameForm + " input[name='your-phone']");
            var $sumateFormLegal = jQuery(nameForm + " input[name='your-legal']");
            
            
            // entidades
            var $sumateFormEntityName = jQuery(nameForm + " input[name='your-entity-name']");
            var $sumateFormContactPerson = jQuery(nameForm + " input[name='your-contact-person']");
            var $sumateFormYourSuggestion = jQuery(nameForm + " textarea[name='your-query']");

            var $errorName = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-name");
            var $errorSurName = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-surname");
            var $errorEmail = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-email");
            var $errorCountry = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-country");
            var $errorPhone = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-phone");
            var $errorFormEntityName = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-entity-name");
            var $errorFormContactPerson = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-contact-person");
            var $errorFormYourSuggestion = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-query");
            var $errorFormLegal = jQuery(nameForm + " .err-legal");
            
            
            var name = $sumateFormName.val(); // get the value of the input field
            var surname = $sumateFormSurname.val();
            var country = $sumateFormCountry.val();
            
            var phone = $sumateFormPhone.val();
            var entityName = $sumateFormEntityName.val();
            var contactPerson = $sumateFormContactPerson.val();
            var query = $sumateFormYourSuggestion.val();
            
            var legal = $sumateFormLegal.is(':checked');
            
            var error = false; // we will set this true if the form isn't valid
            
            if (name === "" || name === " ") {
                $errorName.show(500);
                $errorName.delay(4000);
                $errorName.animate({
                    height: 'toggle'  
                }, 500, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                }); 
                error = true; // change the error state to true
            }
            if (country === "" || country === " ") {
                $errorCountry.show(500);
                $errorCountry.delay(4000);
                $errorCountry.animate({
                    height: 'toggle'  
                }, 500, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                }); 
                error = true; // change the error state to true
            }



            if (phone === "" || phone === " ") {
                $errorPhone.show(500);
                $errorPhone.delay(4000);
                $errorPhone.animate({
                    height: 'toggle'  
                }, 500, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                }); 
                error = true; // change the error state to true
            }

            if (entityName === "" || entityName === " ") {
                $errorFormEntityName.show(500);
                $errorFormEntityName.delay(4000);
                $errorFormEntityName.animate({
                    height: 'toggle'  
                }, 500, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                }); 
                error = true; // change the error state to true
            }
            
            if (contactPerson === "" || contactPerson === " ") {
                $errorFormContactPerson.show(500);
                $errorFormContactPerson.delay(4000);
                $errorFormContactPerson.animate({
                    height: 'toggle'  
                }, 500, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                }); 
                error = true; // change the error state to true
            }
            
            if (query === "" || query === " ") {
                $errorFormYourSuggestion.show(500);
                $errorFormYourSuggestion.delay(4000);
                $errorFormYourSuggestion.animate({
                    height: 'toggle'  
                }, 500, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                }); 
                error = true; // change the error state to true
            }
            
            if (!legal) {
                $errorFormLegal.show(500);
                $errorFormLegal.delay(4000);
                $errorFormLegal.animate({
                    height: 'toggle'  
                }, 500, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                }); 
                error = true; // change the error state to true
            }
            
            var email_compare = /^([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})$/; // Syntax to compare against input
            var email = $sumateFormEmail.val().toLowerCase(); // get the value of the input field

            if (email === "" || email === " " || !email_compare.test(email)) { // check if the field is empty
                $errorEmail.show(500);
                $errorEmail.delay(4000);
                $errorEmail.animate({
                    height: 'toggle'  
                }, 500, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                });         
                error = true;
            }

            return error;
        },
        sendAjaxForm : function (nameForm) {
            
            var dataString = {action:'send_form_sumate'};
            var form = jQuery(nameForm);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : forms_sumate_url.ajax_url,
                type : "POST",
                data : form.serialize(),
                //data : dataString,
                success : function( response ) {
                    
                    console.log(response);
                    
                    if (response.indexOf("OK") !== -1) {
                        jQuery(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, :checkbox, :radio').val('');                    
                        jQuery('.success' + nameForm.replace('#','')).show();
                        
                        var id = uniqId();
                        
                        console.log('id enviado ' + id);
                        // ponerle un settimeout al success y despues esto
                        //adf.ClickTrack(this,687887,'worldcancerresearchday.es/sumate-a-la-iniciativa/TYP',
                        //{orderid: id});
                        
                    } else {
                        jQuery('.ajaxerror').show();
                    }
                    
                                        
                    location.href = "#modal";
                },
                error : function( response ) {
                    
                    jQuery('.ajaxerror').show();
                    
                    location.href = "#modal";
                }
            });
        },
        //contact form submit handler
        sumateFormSubmit: function (nameForm) {
            if (this.validate(nameForm) === false) {
                this.sendAjaxForm(nameForm);
            }
            return false;
        },
        bindEvents: function (nameForm) {    
            this.sumateFormSubmit(nameForm);
        },
        init: function (nameForm) {
            this.bindEvents(nameForm);
            return this;
        }
    };
    

    getCountries();    
   

    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.remodal-confirm', function(e) {  
       jQuery('.successformPersonas').hide();
       jQuery('.successformEntidades').hide();
    });
    
});

function getCountries() {

    var your_country = jQuery(".your-country");
    var html = '';
    
    jQuery.getJSON(forms_sumate_url.url_countries_json, function (json) {        
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var item = json[key];
                
                
                if ( item.name === 'España' && getLang() !== 'en') {
                    //$('option[text=' + item.name + ']').attr('selected','selected');
                    jQuery(".your-country option:contains(" + item.name + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
                }  
                
                
                html +='<option value="' + item.code + '">' + item.name + '</option>';                           
            }
        }        
        var newOption = jQuery(html);
        newOption.insertAfter('.your-country option[value=""]');
    });
    
}

function getLang() {
    // Cogemos idioma
    jQuery.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);        
        if (results !== null) return results[1];
        
        return 'es';
    };
   
    return jQuery.urlParam('lang');
}

function uniqId() {
  return Math.round(new Date().getTime() + (Math.random() * 100));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not right

```
location.href = "#modal";
```

when you need to change hash you need to use window.location.hash = 'modal'

**but** you have another problem!

You need to initialize [your plugin](https://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/) and use [its api](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#remodal)

Instead of this **location.href = "#modal";** you need to use:

```
var inst = jQuery('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal(); 
inst.open()
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, Unbywyd. I really appreciate your help